# mySQL / PHP Log in form not working correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out why this code isn't working. This code is the start of a log in page, but at the moment I cannot advance past this stage. The point of the code at the moment is to output the user details of the user that has just logged in.
I am connected to my database correctly. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$link= mysqli_connect("localhost", "mySql USER NAME", "mySql Password ", "mySql Database name");

if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In") {

    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['logingpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

    print_r($row);

}



?>

<form method="post">

    <input type="email" name="email" id="loginemail"/>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="loginpassword"/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/>

</form>
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`, you should see your porblem there

Comment: no error handling on your connection or your query

Comment: Should `$_POST['loginemail']` be being double md5ed? Also note `name` is what is passed to `$_POST`; not `id`.

Comment: `$_POST['logingpassword']` instead of `$_POST['loginpassword']` might be causing you a bit of a problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, i'm afraid it still wont work correctly but i'll keep at it.  This is what `print_r($_POST)` outputted  `Array ( [loginemail] => [loginpassword] => [submit] => Log In )`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used the incorrect variable name for POST variables in your PHP code for querying the database.

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['logingpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";
```

in the above line there seems to be  mistake in usage of email and password for database query as the HTML form declared POST variable names as name="email" and  name="password" . (I am assuming this is the complete code and that there is no AJAX function used with other variable names to submit this POST request )

Please try the below code instead.

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thought this worked but turned out not too. The same thing is happening with the new query. Any other ideas?